# What is the best way to farm in Dragon Ball Dokan Battle?

Tags: dragon-ball-dokan-battle

I'm happy with this game but the dragon stones, zenies and treasures drop is so scarce. Is there any way to farm faster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Dragon Stones

For dragon stones, it appears that they are dropped mainly while doing the main story quests. Sometimes there are rewards on events, and sometimes on log ins.

Source: [Gamefaqs](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/178921-dragon-ball-z-dokkan-battle/72402249)

> Story quest give a stone for each level on each difficulty and a 2nd
>   for completing a story group on each difficulty. Events depend on the
>   event, usually 1 stone for finishing all difficulties on strikes or 1
>   per difficulty for story events with several stages like the gohan
>   event. Then you have several different missions that give one or more
>   stones. Also some of the login bonuses give stones.
>
> Other than logins, once you do all these things you can't get any more
>   free stones until more content is added. So no repeated farming.

### Treasures and Zenies

Concerning treasures and zennies, it seems that `Area 16 – Reunited: Stage 8 – Ending of the Body Exchange` is a great place to farm a boss called **Pilaf**, who drops 10 Gems and several thousands of zennies.

[image: Pilaf drops]

A complete tutorial and precise article is describing everything you need to know here: [Dokkan Blog](https://dokkanblog.com/dokkan-battle-treasure-farming-made-easy/). The author is explaining how he farmed all those gems. He also precises: running a stage on higher difficulty level grants better drop rates.

> It is best to run this on Z-Hard, as the drop rates are obviously
>   higher when the difficulty is higher[...].